# Spring RestController HTTP status 406 after openjdk jre 7u111 update

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

We've been running a Spring 4 REST application for several months now and all was well. But after an update in Ubuntu 14.04 to "openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3", one of our endpoints now returns an HTTP status of 406 (Not Acceptable). Nothing else had changed, just the JRE version.

The rest endpoint in question looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<DriverRegistration> registerNewDriver(
    @PathVariable String username, 
    @RequestBody RegistrationRequest regRequest,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

   ...

}
```

There are also other endpoints in the controller that begin with /{username} and have additional path elements after /{username}. But this never presented a problem prior to this java update. I also tested the controller with all other endpoints removed and the problem persists.

Spring is version 4.3.2 but the problem also exists with 4.3.1. We are running under Wildfly 8.2 with an nginx reverse proxy in front, though the problem manifests even if accessing the wildfly server directly.

I enabled debug level logging for org.springframework.

Log extract from server running the prior JRE version, which works as expected:

```
2016-08-26 08:59:43,203 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/rest/driver/example@mycompany.com]
2016-08-26 08:59:43,204 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (default task-11) Looking up handler method for path /driver/example@mycompany.com
2016-08-26 08:59:43,207 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (default task-11) Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.mycompany.argonaut.model.DriverRegistration> com.mycompany.argonaut.rest.driver.DriverAppController.registerNewDriver(java.lang.String,com.mycompany.argonaut.rest.driver.DriverAppController$RegistrationRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2016-08-26 08:59:43,207 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (default task-11) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'driverAppController'
2016-08-26 08:59:43,208 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor] (default task-11) Read [class com.mycompany.argonaut.rest.driver.DriverAppController$RegistrationRequest] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@54b2c343]
2016-08-26 08:59:43,346 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor] (default task-11) Written [com.mycompany.argonaut.model.DriverRegistration@11f6853c] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@54b2c343]
2016-08-26 08:59:43,347 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-08-26 08:59:43,347 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) Successfully completed request
```

Log extract from server running updated JRE:

```
2016-08-26 08:59:51,416 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/mycompany-rest/driver/example@mycompany.com]
2016-08-26 08:59:51,417 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (default task-11) Looking up handler method for path /driver/example@mycompany.com
2016-08-26 08:59:51,419 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-11) Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2016-08-26 08:59:51,419 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] (default task-11) Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2016-08-26 08:59:51,419 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-11) Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2016-08-26 08:59:51,419 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-08-26 08:59:51,420 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-11) Successfully completed request
```

In this case the method for the endpoint is never called. So there is nothing in the body of the method that could fix this. I'm guessing they only way I could further influence the mapping would be in the annotation, but just don't see any other options there that would help.

Though not really a solution, it is interesting to note that if a trailing slash is appended after the {username} parameter, the request is successful under either JRE version.

So I don't really know where to go with this. Is it a Spring bug? is it an OpenJDK bug? Why is Spring now unable to map this request? Is there any way to further assist the Spring request mapping to avoid this error?

**Update:**

Requested code... This has always mapped just fine automatically via Jackson.

```
public class RegistrationRequest {
  private String password;
  private int employeeNum;
  private String ssnDigits;
  private int confirmationNumber;

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public int getEmployeeNum() {
    return employeeNum;
  }

  public void setEmployeeNum(int employeeNum) {
    this.employeeNum = employeeNum;
  }

  public String getSsnDigits() {
    return ssnDigits;
  }

  public void setSsnDigits(String ssnDigits) {
    this.ssnDigits = ssnDigits;
  }

  public int getConfirmationNumber() {
    return confirmationNumber;
  }

  public void setConfirmationNumber(int confirmationNumber) {
    this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
  }

}
```

I've been using the ARC app in chrome to troubleshoot and my input json looks like this:

```
{
  "employeeNum":1234,
  "password":"123456",
  "ssnDigits":"5678",
  "confirmationNumber":0
}
```

Comment: Can you post the RegistrationRequest class and an example json document?

Comment: What do your request headers look like?  406 is an http content type negotiation issue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation

Comment: Request headers are as expected, Content-Type: application/json, Accept: application/json. This all worked before the JRE update. And adding a trailing slash in the request url makes it work, for reasons unknown.